# CSS3 Background position transition

Tags: css, animation

i know many questions has been asked about this topic already but I don't seem to find someone who has the exact same Issue than me.

**FYI : I am using FF 53.0.2**

So this is what I want to achieve : I have gradient containing 12 colors (one for each month of the year) in background and I want to use altogether background-size and background-position properties in order to create an effect where the background would change when triggered (application change a class on body).

The problem is that when I change lets say `background-position:0 500%;` to `background-position:0 600%;` the transition seems to occur from `background-position:0 0;` so the whole background scroll until 600% is reached, which makes no sense at all.

is there a way to tweak this to prevent the background-position bug?

**There is a snippet to help you understand:**

```js
var month = 1;
setInterval(function(){
  month++;
  if(month > 12){ month = 1; }
  $('#wrapper').attr('class', '').addClass('month-'+month);
}, 2500);
```

```css
.box{
  position:relative;display:block;
  width:100%;height:450px;
  
  background: #9c54dc;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9c54dc 0%, #6d65ff 9%, #517fff 18%, #14a0ff 27%, #1ad1c0 36%, #6adc57 45%, #ffd21a 54%, #ffb41a 63%, #ff591a 72%, #ff1a1a 81%, #ff6666 91%, #b233fc 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #9c54dc 0%,#6d65ff 9%,#517fff 18%,#14a0ff 27%,#1ad1c0 36%,#6adc57 45%,#ffd21a 54%,#ffb41a 63%,#ff591a 72%,#ff1a1a 81%,#ff6666 91%,#b233fc 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #9c54dc 0%,#6d65ff 9%,#517fff 18%,#14a0ff 27%,#1ad1c0 36%,#6adc57 45%,#ffd21a 54%,#ffb41a 63%,#ff591a 72%,#ff1a1a 81%,#ff6666 91%,#b233fc 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c54dc', endColorstr='#b233fc',GradientType=0 );

 -webkit-background-size:100% 1200%;
 -moz-background-size:100% 1200%;
 -o-background-size:100% 1200%;
 background-size:100% 1200%;

 background-position:0% 0%;
  
  -webkit-transition:background-position 2s ease;
 -moz-transition:background-position 2s ease;
 -o-transition:background-position 2s ease;
 transition:background-position 2s ease;
}

#wrapper.month-1 .box{
 background-position:0 0;
}

#wrapper.month-2 .box{
 background-position:0 100%;
}

#wrapper.month-3 .box{
 background-position:0 200%;
}

#wrapper.month-4 .box{
 background-position:0 300%; 
}

#wrapper.month-5 .box{
 background-position:0 400%;
}

#wrapper.month-6 .box{
 background-position:0 500%;
}

#wrapper.month-7 .box{
 background-position:0 600%;
}

#wrapper.month-8 .box{
 background-position:0 700%;
}

#wrapper.month-9 .box{
 background-position:0 800%;
}

#wrapper.month-10 .box{
 background-position:0 900%;
}

#wrapper.month-11 .box{
 background-position:0 1000%;
}

#wrapper.month-12 .box{
 background-position:0 1100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="month-1">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanna make sure I'm understanding the question.  Do you want to just have the background cover the entire page or is there an issue with the actual gradient transition?

Comment: @trav Hello, the 'covering' part is correct. I am transitionning the background-position depending on current 'month'. That is why the background-size actually takes 1200% and moving the position up 100% for each month. The 'transition' need is that users will be able to select manually a month so I need to do a smooth transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background-position is relative to the whole size of the background.

So, since you have 12 months, every month takes 1/12 of the total

```js
var month = 1;
setInterval(function(){
  month++;
  if(month > 12){ month = 1; }
  $('#wrapper').attr('class', '').addClass('month-'+month);
}, 2500);
```

```css
.box{
  position:relative;display:block;
  width:100%;height:450px;
  
  background: #9c54dc;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9c54dc 0%, #6d65ff 9%, #517fff 18%, #14a0ff 27%, #1ad1c0 36%, #6adc57 45%, #ffd21a 54%, #ffb41a 63%, #ff591a 72%, #ff1a1a 81%, #ff6666 91%, #b233fc 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #9c54dc 0%,#6d65ff 9%,#517fff 18%,#14a0ff 27%,#1ad1c0 36%,#6adc57 45%,#ffd21a 54%,#ffb41a 63%,#ff591a 72%,#ff1a1a 81%,#ff6666 91%,#b233fc 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #9c54dc 0%,#6d65ff 9%,#517fff 18%,#14a0ff 27%,#1ad1c0 36%,#6adc57 45%,#ffd21a 54%,#ffb41a 63%,#ff591a 72%,#ff1a1a 81%,#ff6666 91%,#b233fc 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9c54dc', endColorstr='#b233fc',GradientType=0 );

 -webkit-background-size:100% 1200%;
 -moz-background-size:100% 1200%;
 -o-background-size:100% 1200%;
 background-size:100% 1200%;

 background-position:0% 0%;
  
  -webkit-transition:background-position 2s ease;
 -moz-transition:background-position 2s ease;
 -o-transition:background-position 2s ease;
 transition:background-position 2s ease;
}

#wrapper.month-1 .box{
 background-position:0 0;
}

#wrapper.month-2 .box{
 background-position:0 8.3%;   /* new value */
}

#wrapper.month-3 .box{
 background-position:0 16.6%;  /* new value */
}

#wrapper.month-4 .box{
 background-position:0 25%; /* new value */
}

#wrapper.month-5 .box{
 background-position:0 33.3%;
}

#wrapper.month-6 .box{
 background-position:0 41.6%;
}

#wrapper.month-7 .box{
 background-position:0 50%;
}

#wrapper.month-8 .box{
 background-position:0 58.3%;
}

#wrapper.month-9 .box{
 background-position:0 66.7%;
}

#wrapper.month-10 .box{
 background-position:0 75%;
}

#wrapper.month-11 .box{
 background-position:0 83.3%;
}

#wrapper.month-12 .box{
 background-position:0 91.6%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="month-1">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```